# replacing CKEditor instance on multiple text fields, but not all

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have 20 text fields in a form, I only want CKEditor functionality on 10.  I could do it by creating this for each text field:

```
//Setup CKEditor for textarea
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'textareaname', {
        extraPlugins: 'wordcount',  // enable wordcount plugin; customized to show count on top
        removePlugins: 'elementspath', // don't want the elements path in the corner
        resize_enabled: false,
        ForcePasteAsPlainText: true,
        height: 100,
        removeFormatTags: 'form,div,span,font,form,table,tr,td,input,textarea,script,a,p,br',
        toolbar: [ ['Cut','Copy','PasteText','-','Bold','Italic','-','Undo','Redo','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'] ],
        // This last section sets tag endings not to use "/>" (since not using XML)
        on:
        {
            instanceReady : function( ev )
            {
                this.dataProcessor.writer.selfClosingEnd = '>';
            }
        }
    });
```

but I would rather have one statement for all, rather than ten.  I have tried listing all the text areas and adding a class to all the textareas I want and trying to call CKEDITOR.replace "class name" in various forms, but that doesn't seem to work either.  Is there an easy way to get just the fields I want without each one having a separate statment?

Here is what I currently have.  Not showing any errors, the text fields are just not being converted to CKEDITOR. Still new at Javascript...

$('.makeck').each(function () { CKEDITOR.replace(this,  {
            extraPlugins: 'wordcount',  // enable wordcount plugin; customized to show count on top
            removePlugins: 'elementspath', // don't want the elements path in the corner
            resize_enabled: false,
            ForcePasteAsPlainText: true,
            height: 100,
            removeFormatTags: 'form,div,span,font,form,table,tr,td,input,textarea,script,a,p,br',
            toolbar: [ ['Cut','Copy','PasteText','-','Bold','Italic','-','Undo','Redo','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'] ],
        // This last section sets tag endings not to use "/>" (since not using XML)
        on:
        {
            instanceReady : function( ev )
            {
                this.dataProcessor.writer.selfClosingEnd = '>';
            }
        }
    });

Comment: Try looping the elements? `$('.myClassNameAppliedToAllTargetFields').each(function () { CKEDITOR.replace(this, { ... }); });`

Comment: Tried using function, but still can't get to to work. Looked at other question, no help either.  Just going to leave as individual statements.

Comment: That is also known as "giving up" :p Edit your question to include what, if any error you get when you try to do what the duplicate question suggests, and I'll take a look. What isn't working? Any errors in console? Give detail, and you'll get more help. Give up, and you'll never advance.

Comment: Sorry, Chris - you are right.  I think the problem is my lack of javascript knowledge.  I am still fairly new at it and can't quit get the knack. I will edit question and see what happens.  Thanks for the encouragement.